# Winform Caching

Tags: winforms, caching

Is there a Winform caching library out there? I need to pass a few datasets aroung in a Winform Application, and probably persist to storage upon close.

I've seen some samples around via Google, using System.Web.

What's the recommendation and where can I get some details. I am using VS 2008 for 2.0. 3.0 Framework.

Thanks

Comment: A good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523221/caching-strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with .NET 2.0 you can use the System.Web.Caching.Cache class with non-ASP.NET apps. The Microsoft recommended approach these days though is to use the Enterprise Library Caching Application Block.

Comment: I am aware of these, but was checking for a lightweight alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the dataset to some temporary storage mechanism then DataSet does support ToXml() and FromXml() capabilities (I forget the exact method names).